# IIS 7.0 StaticFile Error

Tags: iis-7, windows-server

My project is based on ASP.NET 4.5, it works in my local machine with Visual Studio 2013. And it also works well in Windows Server 2012 R, but when I put it into IIS 7.0 in Windows Server Standard (32 bit), a error is thrown;

Module: IIS Web Core
Info: MapRequestHandler
handle: StaticFile
Code 0x80070002

I had registered .NET v4 and added aspnet_isapi.dll to handle map, i had set the path of the StaticFile to '*'.

But it still doesn't work well.

How to deal with it.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/13130380/4334575][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13130380/4334575

This answer solve my  problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue before, I think you have to register the .net framework in IIS.

Open a command line window and navigate to 
c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64[your .net version]\
and type
aspnet_regiis -i

Comment: see if this helps  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941718/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-falls-through-to-the-static-file-handler

Comment: Thank you. I make it by adding the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" to the <modules> tag: