# Error 404 in WCF app on local or remote IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config

I create small WCF app. This app fine work on IIS Express. But when I publish this app on local or remote IIS, I catch error: "IIS Web Core MapRequestHandler StaticFile"

This Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Gate.Service1" >
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:10808" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="/list/"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="Gate.IService1"
              behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour"
                  />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehaviour">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
I reinstall ASP.NET, But it didn't fix problem

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -i
```

Comment: Look at this post. It may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941718/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-falls-through-to-the-static-file-handler